# What is the significance of . $1 in the below script

Tags: bash

Could you please help me to understand the significance of `. $1` in the script below.

```
# source the config file after checking for a valid file
if [ -f $1 ]
then
    echo "File path " $1
else
    echo "Not a valid filename"
    exit 1
fi
curr_dir=$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )
country='AU'

. $1
echo "========Printing config properties====="
cat $1
```

Comment: The comment at the top (`# source the config file after checking for a valid file`) explains what it does, and suggests the term 'source' as something you could research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1` is the first argument. The script supposes the first argument will be a file (whence the `[ -f $1]`).

suppose in the file variables and/or functions are declared, running

```
. $1
```

will make those variables and functions available for use in your script. You are sort of "including" the file `$1` in you script.

Answer (score 1):

$1 is the first parameter to shell script.

```
. $1
```

will execute the bash script file if $1 contains the name of that file. If it doesnt contain the name of a bash script then appropriate error will be shown.

for example :

```
  $ i=test.sh
  $ . $i
```

will execute the file test.sh in the current directory

Comment: Thanks everyone. .$1 is abeautiful way of passing paramter file into our main script.